# Polymer 1.0 - Styles not working for computed class attribute

Tags: css, polymer, polymer-1.0

Here's the [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/cuhavag/edit?html,output).

When giving the `paper-card` a `class="red"` with the `_computedClass()` function it doesn't apply the `paper-card.red` styles.

Highlighted in the screenshot below is the `paper-card` with the `class="red"` just like the one above it, but the styles aren't applying. I'd expect the background to be red as well.

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before v1.6.0, Polymer's custom property shim applied styles only once at creation time (before bindings are applied). Also from Polymer [docs on Styling](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling#dynamism-limitations):

> #### Dynamism limitations
>
> Only property definitions which match the element at creation time are applied. Any dynamic changes that update property values are not applied automatically. You can force styles to be re-evaluated by calling the `updateStyles` method on a Polymer element, or `Polymer.updateStyles` to update all element styles.

So you could call [`this.updateStyles()`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/Polymer.Base#method-updateStyles) in your `attached` callback to apply the CSS mixin from the custom property:

```
Polymer({
  ...
  attached: function() {
    this.updateStyles();
  }
);
```

[jsbin](https://jsbin.com/xacinas/1/edit?html,output)

Alternatively, you could upgrade to the latest Polymer release (v1.7.0), which includes support for native CSS properties (released in [v1.6.0](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/releases/tag/v1.6.0)). This obviates the need to call `this.updateStyles()` to apply dynamic CSS styles. Make sure to set `lazyRegister:true` and `useNativeCSSProperties:true` before importing `polymer.html`:

```
<script>
  window.Polymer = {
    ...
    lazyRegister: true,
    useNativeCSSProperties: true
  };
</script>
<link rel="import" href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.0/components/polymer/polymer.html">
```

[jsbin](https://jsbin.com/kixixu/edit?html,output)